# Where to post questions about building computers?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Where is the right place to post questions pertaining to building computer systems and related hardware components?

Comment: See http://superuser.com/faq  Hardware is on topic there, but not buying recommendations, etc.

Answer (score 11):

[Super User](http://superuser.com).

From the [FAQ](https://superuser.com/faq):

> Super User is for computer enthusiasts and power users. If you have a question about …
>
> - computer hardware
> - computer software

Comment: I just asked a question on superuser after reading this answer and I think it will be closed :(

Comment: @Vikas - it's probably because people think that your question is asking for opinions rather than a concrete answer.

Comment: but I think it isn't opinion based. Either you can build a pc like that or you can't? No?

Answer (score 11):

[Super User](https://superuser.com/) is the place for you, though you should peruse the [Help Center](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic) first.  In general, hardware questions will be on topic for SU as long as you're not looking for

> a shopping or buying recommendation

Of course, if you mean building as in building from transistors and diodes, then you probably want [Electronics](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/), but I don't think that's what you're talking about.

Answer (score 7):

[**Super User**](https://superuser.com/) is our site for computer hardware and software, so it should be a perfect fit there. A [cursory search](https://superuser.com/search?q=build+computer) yields thousands of results blindly, most of which do appear to deal with building the machine (rather than, say, code builds or summat). The closed questions are closed not for being off-topic, but for other reasons. So as long as you have a solid question to ask on your hardware, you'll be fine at Super User. ♪