# Where to ask questions about computer parts?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, specific-question, site-recommendation

I have some questions about computer hardware. Which stack exchange site would be best suited for this?

Comment: What kind of question? If it is a "what is the best...?" or "which should I get?", they don't belong anywhere on the network.

Comment: About computer power supplies and why they might burn out or go bad.

Comment: [electronics](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/) may be suitable. Check out their FAQ and make sure the question follows it.

Comment: See also: [Where to post questions about building computers?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/98299)/

Comment: See also: [Hardware questions and Stack Exchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/57998)

Comment: See also: [Where am I supposed to post a question regarding hardware?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/153651)

Answer (score 11):

> `if (!$(question).is("shopping question")) {`
>   　　`return $.ajax(`"[SuperUser](https://superuser.com/)"`);`
>   `}`

Comment: Not enough jQuery.

Comment: yes needs more jquery

Comment: More jQuery for ya.

Comment: @Antony cept you removed the link :P

Comment: you can optimize: `if(!$(question).is("shopping question")) { return SuperUser }`. All others are undefined.

Comment: @ChristopherW Syntax error: you missed a `)`.

Comment: @Antony So I did (fixed it)!

Comment: Okay. I had some computer power supplies burn out. So I will try super user. Thanks

Comment: @KrisHollenbeck: You mean SMPS or power cable ?

Comment: I don't know? What do you mean by SMPS? What is that suppose to stand for?

Comment: @KrisHollenbeck: do you own a PC or mac? [SMPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switched-mode_power_supply)

Comment: PC.............................

Comment: @KrisHollenbeck: if you see the CPU, place where you plugin the power cable-that is SMPS. It contains a FAN visible in the CPU.

Comment: @ChristopherW Enough jQuery. We should stop now. Don't play around for so long.

Comment: @AnoopVaidya The reason behind this complicated formatting is to retain the link among the codes.

Comment: @Antony:    OIC...

Comment: @AnoopVaidya I figured out a way to do this: Put the code in a `<pre>` tag and link to the site with `<a>`. But seriously I don't want to bump this question again.

Comment: @Antony: I tried to change as I do in  SO, in code, but less reps here... :)

Answer (score 4):

[Superuser](http://superuser.com)....

A lot of computers, softwares and hardware related questions....

[image]